# How to find out whether this function: $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is injective?

Tags: functions

How to find out whether this function: $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is injective? Is it easy to make a graph of this function or should I solve this problem differently than through a graph - I would prefer different method if making graph is too difficult.. I have tried following method, but I do not know how to express one variable by the other: $\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{u}{u^2+1}$

Comment: I wounder where all these people get the impression that problems might be solved by *making graphs*, since human beings cannot *make* graphs.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that by definition $f(x)$ is injective when

$$a\neq b \implies f(a)\neq f(b)$$

then assume

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}=k \implies kx^2-x+k=0$$

and since

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4k^2}}{2k}$$

we obtain $2$ distinct solutions $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=k$ for any $k$ such that $1-4k^2>0$.

Comment: Very good, thank you! Actually I have tried similar method. I have assumed that  $x/x^2+1=u/u^2+1$ but I could not solve the problem..

Comment: @TKN Yes I think this way is simpler!

Comment: @TKN As an alternative and as a more general method, since $f(x)$ is continuous and we have that for $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1/2$ and $lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$ therefore by EVT theorem a maximum exists and by IVT $a$ and $b$ exist with $a\neq b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: But is it possible to apply your method for example to this function?: $f(x)=x+(1/x)$ . If I assume that $x+(1/x)=k$ , I do not know how to distinguish whether it is injective or not.. How would you solve that?

Comment: @TKN Are you referring to $\frac{x+1}x$?

Comment: No, I refer to this x+(1/x)

Comment: @TKN In that case we obtain $x^2-kx+1=0$ that is $x=\frac{k\pm \sqrt{k^2-4}}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry I see where is the problem now... I made a mistake.. Thanks again!

Comment: @TKN You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Subtract your right-hand side from your left-hand side, and put them over a common denominator.
You are looking for the solution when the numerator is zero. 
  It will be zero when $x=u$, so $(x-u)$ must be a factor of the numerator.  What is the other factor ?

Comment: Straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) =\frac{1}{x+\frac1 x}$$ So we have $f(x) = f(\frac 1 x) $ so take any $x\not\in\{1,0,-1\}$ i.e $x=2$ to get $f(2)=f(\frac12)$.

Comment: kingw3.Nice.(2,1/2)(3,1/3)(4,1/4)....

Comment: It looks like you meant to write $f(2) = f(1/2)$.  To get a counterexample to the claim that $f$ is injective using your method, we cannot let $x = 1, 0, -1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Indeed I was in a hurry so I haven't noticed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using your method:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{u}{u^2+1} \Rightarrow xu^2+x=ux^2+u \Rightarrow \\
xu(u-x)-(u-x)=0 \Rightarrow (u-x)(xu-1)=0$$
Since $x\ne u$, then by choosing $xu=1$, we can make $f(x)=f(u)$. Indeed:
$$f(2)=\frac{2}{2^2+1}=\frac25,\\
f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\frac12}{\left(\frac12\right)^2+1}=\frac25.$$
So, it is not injective.

Alternatively, you can check its derivative:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} \ \ \begin{cases}>0, |x|<1\\ <0,|x|>1\end{cases}$$
Since, the function is increasing and decreasing, there must be two different points $x_1\ne x_2$, where $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, get out your graph paper!

Since $f(0) = 0$, plot the point $(0,0)$.

Since $f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$, plot the point $(1,\frac{1}{2})$.

Since $f(2) = \frac{2}{5}$, plot the point $(2,\frac{2}{5})$.

For several centuries technicians, with graph paper in hand, have accepted the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#History). Since $0 \lt \frac{2}{5} \lt \frac{1}{2}$ we can confidently state that the function is not injective.

But for the skeptics, they can input

$\quad \text{solve } x/(x^2+1) = 2/5$

into [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%20%3D%202%2F5).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely unnecessary but interesting solution: substitute $x=\tan\theta$. Then the function becomes $$\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac12\sin(2\theta).$$
Now, $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $\sin$ is not injective over $(-\pi,\pi)$. Since $\tan$ is a bijection from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $\mathbb R$, it follows that $f$ is not injective.